# Print values of keys with dot in it

Tags: yq

I have a yaml file with the following format

```
---
users:
  foo1.bar1@email.com:
    - roles/role1
    - roles/role2
    - roles/role3

  foo2.bar2@email.com:
    - roles/role4
    - roles/role5
    - roles/role6
```

Now I would like to print the roles for foo1.bar1@email.com

Im trying to do the following

```
cat permissions.yaml | yq '.users[ foo1.bar1@email.com]'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FORMAT (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.users[ foo1.bar1@email.com]
jq: 1 compile error
```

Is there a work around to this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using v3 (or later) of **mikefarah/yq** you can escape keys with quotes, like this:

```
cat permissions.yaml | yq e '.users."foo1.bar1@email.com"' -
```

or

```
cat permissions.yaml | yq e '.users["foo1.bar1@email.com"]' -
```

Documented in v3 [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/usage/path-expressions#special-characters) and in v4 [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/traverse-read#nested-special-characters).

I verified this with v4.13.4:

```
$ yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.13.4
```

Comment: This answer deserves "Accepted'

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the whitespace in front of your key:

```
cat permissions.yaml | yq '.users[foo1.bar1@email.com]'
```

That might resolve it.